# How do you test a specific image file extension in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, validation, minitest

I have a custom validation to prevent uploads of image file types other than JPG or PNG for an Account `logo`.

Is it possible to stub a file with a specific file extension to test the patch action of the controller handling the upload ?

This is what the custom validation looks like:

```
has_one_attached :logo

validate :correct_logo_file_type

def correct_logo_file_type
    if logo.attached? && !logo.content_type.in?(%w(image/jpg image/png))
      errors.add(:logo, :incorrect_file_type)
    end
end
```

Comment: one this you can do instead of having the function is to write it as: `validates_format_of :image, with: %r{\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$}i, message: "your message"`

Answer (score 0):

ACCEPTABLE_TYPES = ['image/png', 'image/gif'].freeze

has_one_attached :screenshot, dependent: :destroy

validate :acceptable_image

private

def acceptable_image

return true unless screenshot.attached?

errors.add(:screenshot, 'must be a PNG or GIF') unless ACCEPTABLE_TYPES.include?(screenshot.content_type)

end